# laravel query don't return same result on local and on production

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I use laravel for my web app, and here is the problem, my local machine and production server have same data, **but this code don't return same results**, why ?

```
Table::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->where('column_1',$int)->where('column_2',$tring)->where('column_3','string')->first();
```

I local it's ok, but on my server is always null (**except when i try it in artisan -tinker**).

Can you help me ?

**EDIT :**

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsCwq.png)

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25YIl.png)

When i try this code :

```
$DayNBExist = Table::whereDate('created_at',date('Y-m-d'))->where(['profile_id'=>$id,'country'=>$country,'type'=>'user'])->first();

    if(!isset($DayNBExist->id)){

        Table::create([
            'nbr'=>1,
            'profile_id'=>$Channel->id,
            'country' => $country,
            'type' => 'channel',
        ]);

    }else{

        $DayNBExist->increment('nbr');

    }
```

it create new line, not update the old line. **why ?**

**THANKS ALL THE PROBLEM WASN'T THE CODE BUT in "$country" value**

Comment: Are you certain they have the same data, including the `created_at` stamps? And is `$tring` a typo? I strongly suspect that should be `$string`. If that's not your problem, you're going to need to post more information, such as the structure of your table.

Comment: can you check my edit ?

Comment: I see your edit, but you didn’t really answer my first two questions to you.

Comment: when i said no return same results i mean,  in local this code no have a problem, when he found same date, it's increment. but on production that query always add new line in DB.  and when new line is created, this query is always null. ps : what mean typo ?

Comment: That still doesn’t answer my question about the data. You said both machines have the “same data.” Are you certain of that? And “typo” means “typographical error.” `$tring` is a very strange variable name. Are you sure that should not be `$string`?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. when I said "same data", I thought the "same type" of data. I wanted to write $string but in the speed I erased the "s".

Comment: other "strange" things : when i use that code outside the controller the result is not null...

Comment: Why would you expect the same results if you *don't* have the same data in both places? We can't help you find the real problem if your question makes incorrect statements about your data and your code has typographical errors. Please edit your post to correct all of the typos and explain clearly what you need, what you have tried, and what isn't working. Be sure you include a [mcve] and clear description of the expected results and actual results.

Comment: @Gottam, typo is kind of grammar syntax error when you're typing. Comme une faute de frappe. `$tring` is supposed to be `$string` normally. Try to debug value of `date('Y-m-d');` passing it from Laravel to javascript `console.log(...);`. Check your Laravel PHP `timezone` is the same as you MySql `timezone`.

Comment: @KeitelDOG merci !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply 
I think the main reason as

`servertime` and your `localmachine` are not same

Please Configure your time  `'timezone' => 'UTC',`  which can be found in

```
Project/config/app.php
```

Or there is a other way but it is not recommemnded for laravel

add

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

in your index.php (inside your public folder)